# Extract text from images

Tags: java

I am looking for a programmatic way to retrieve an editable text from images. I am aware of free Ocrtool. The output will shown as *.png* format character. How to convert this into editable text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18845865/how-to-extract-text-from-jpeg-tif-files

Comment: Have you checked this:- http://roncemer.com/software-development/java-ocr/ ?

Answer (score 3):

[Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) will yield a text document for a given image, so it should do what you are after. Since you are using Java, you will be needing [Tess4J](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/P9REq9OkKZY).

Answer (score 0):

As npinti said, `Tess4j` is great and usable.There is another solution :

[`JavaCV`](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/) provides you a bridge to `OpenCV` which can help you realizing what you want to do

You can for example look at how `Sikuli` use it to OCR texts in the `sikuli-core` [repo](https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli-core/tree/master/src/main/java/org/sikuli/core/cv)